# What does Ctrl-S specifically do in Chrome Dev tools Sources tab?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The local save feature of the Chrome Dev tools Sources tab is very powerful.

However, I can't completely tell what kind of changes actually hold.

What changes are actually activated?

Comment: Really, beats me. I think it's still a new thing that needs development before Chrome becomes some kind of fully-fledged web editor!

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-S applies your changes into v8.
So the the dynamic page behavior will work differently according to the changed code.

The star symbol in the file title indicates that the recent changes in the file haven't been sent to v8.

You have to save the changed file to the place where the web server gets it if you want to see the changes after reloading the page. You could do that with help of context menu.

Comment: That's why I could never get my dynamic changes to take effect!  I always ended up saving them on the server and refreshing the page.

Comment: It seems like you cannot add functions though.  You can only modify functions that already exist.  So, I'm looking to understand what types of things work once sent into v8 and what do not.